# Upper bound of $f(y) -f(x)$ with $f$ $L$-smooth and concave

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, upper-lower-bounds

> **Lemma**: Given $f(x)$ convex and $L$-smooth then $$f(y)-f(x)\leq \nabla f(y)^T(y-x) - \frac{1}{2L}||\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x)||_2^2.$$

In order to prove this lemma the following are used:

1. Because of the convexity of $f$ we have $$f(z)\geq f(y) + \nabla f(y)^T(z-y) \iff \\ f(y)-f(z) \leq \nabla f(y)^T(y-z) \tag{1}$$
2. Because $f$ is $L$ smooth we have:
   $$f(z)\leq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T (z-x) + \frac{L}{2}||z-x||_2^2 \iff \\ f(z)-f(x) \leq \nabla f(x)^T (z-x) + \frac{L}{2}||z-x||_2^2\tag{2}$$ Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have:
   $$f(y)-f(x)=f(y)-f(z)+f(z)+f(x)\leq \\\nabla f(y)^T (y-z) + \nabla f(x)^T (z-x) + \frac{L}{2}||z-x||_2^2 \tag{3}.$$ The minimum of he right side of inequality is $z=x-\frac{1}{L}(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)).$ Substituting $z$ in the previous inequality we have:
   $$f(y)-f(x)\leq \nabla f(y)^T(y-x) -\frac{1}{2L}||\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)||\tag{4}.$$

I am trying to conclude with a similar lemma but with $f$ is concave. I started with the same rationale but with:
$$f(z)\leq f(y) + \nabla f(y)^T(z-y) \iff \\ f(y)-f(z) \geq \nabla f(y)^T(z-y) \iff \\ f(z)-f(y) \geq \nabla f(y)^T(y-z) \tag{5}$$ instead of $(1)$ as $f$ is concave now. Starting with the same rationale and combining $(2)$ and $(5)$, $$f(y)-f(x)=f(y)-f(z)+f(z)+f(x)=\dots$$ does not help. Is it possible to prove the lemma with $f$ concave? How should we proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: @angryavian thanks for the interest, but if $f$ is concave how should we apply $L$-strong convexity? Is there an analog for concave functions?

Comment: Can we state that for the maximization of a concave function $f$ we have to minimize the convex function $-f$ and then inequality $(4)$ transformed into 

$$-f(y)-(-f(x))\leq \nabla (-f(y))^T(y-x) -\frac{1}{2L}||\nabla (-f(x)) - \nabla (-f(y))|| \iff \\f(y)-f(x) \geq \nabla f(y)^T(y-x) -\frac{1}{2L}||\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)||$$